# Jquery Hide table rows

Tags: jquery

I am hiding a bunch of textboxes and it works fine, the problem is, the textboxes are in a  table, so I also need to hide the corresponding labels.
the structure is something like this

```
<tr>
<td>
Label
</td>
<td>
InputFile
</td>
</tr>
```

in fact its just easier if I hide the rows that have a fileinput , can someone help please

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what 'fileinput' or 'InputFile' is actually referring to? Is it an 'input type="text"' with a certain class, or an 'input type="file"'?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

this might work for you...

```
$('.trhideclass1').hide();
```

```
<tr class="trhideclass1">
  <td>Label</td>
  <td>InputFile</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: In my opinion, it's best to keep the markup as clean and concise as possible, both for maintenance and readability.

Comment: (Also, the intent of the question is surely 'how do I hide an element that contains a given element' not just 'how do I hide an element with a given class')

Comment: Thanks Derek, your answer was the best solution in this case

Comment: Thank you very much, this is a life saver for a big project I had to make a whole lot of form changes on :)

Answer (score 20):

You just need to traverse up the DOM tree to the nearest `<tr>` like so...

```
$("#ID_OF_ELEMENT").parents("tr").hide();
```

[jQuery API Reference](http://api.jquery.com/parents/)

Comment: I think that should be parents(), not parent()

Comment: Down vote -1.  parent() takes the first element.  parents() is the correct usage.

Comment: @Bobby @ICodeForCoffee You guys are right; I've updated my answer

Comment: parents("tr") would hide any tr above. 
if you have a table in table, this solution is not working. 
use closest("tr") instead

Answer (score 10):

This should do the trick.

```
$(textInput).closest("tr").hide();
```

Answer (score 2):

`$('inputFile').parent().parent().children('td > label').hide();`

can help you navigate two levels up ( to TD, to TR ) moving two levels back down ( all TD's in that TR and their LABEL tags ), applying the hide() function there.

if you want to stay at the TR level and hide them:

`$('inputFile').parent().parent().hide();`

… is sufficient.

you can navigate very easily through the elements using the jquery selectors.

parent is documented here:
http://api.jquery.com/parent/

hide is documented here:
http://api.jquery.com/hide/

Answer (score 2):

**html**

```
<tr><td><a href="" onclick=hideRow(event)></a></td></tr>
```

**jquery**

```
function hideRow(event){
  $(event.target || event.srcElement).parents('tr').hide();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the label is in a table row you can do this to hide the row:

```
('.InputFile').parent().Hide()
```

You can refine your selector as you need and then get the table row that contains that element.

JQuery Selectors help:  http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

**EDIT**  This is the correct way to do it.

```
    ('.InputFile').parents('tr').hide()
```

Comment: -1 The parent of the input control would be the `<td>`, and the hide method is lower-case

Answer (score 1):

Using `parents('tr').hide()` works. However if there is an embedded table, all parent `tr` rows will be hidden.  In my case, the entire form is hidden since there are many embedded tables.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet if you want both text field and label to hide simultaneously is assign each with a class and hide them like this:

```
jQuery(".labelClass, .inputClass").hide();
```